# How to Add a Conditional whereField to a Firestore Query

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm querying Firestore collections using `.whereField`. Depending on the user input, it may be a single-condition or multiple-condition query. E.g.,

```
myCollection
.whereField("color", isEqualTo: selectedColorArgument)
.whereField("shape", isEqualTo: selectedShapeArgument)
```

How can I code this query so that a condition is only queried for when a value is selected? E.g., if no "shape" is selected, then there should not be a `.whereField("shape", isEqualTo: selectedShapeArgument)` condition considered in the query. I was considering a switch statement but there would too many cases with more possible conditions to select.

Comment: When you say single or multiple conditions - for multiple conditions, is this a logical OR or AND? e.g. color == "blue" AND shape = "parallelepiped"? or does it mean one or the other; either color OR shape?

Answer (score 2):

Firestore queries follow a builder pattern, where each call to [`whereField`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Query#wherefield_:isequalto:) returns a new `Query` object.

So you can initialize a query variable like this:

```
Query query = myCollection;
```

And then conditionally replace the variable for each condition:

```
if condition {
  query = query.whereField("color", isEqualTo: selectedColorArgument)
}
if condition2 {
  query = query.whereField("shape", isEqualTo: selectedShapeArgument)
}
```

Comment: Swift? `var query: Query = myCollection` This will create a logical AND, correct?

Comment: Multiple `where...` calls in Firestore are (currently) always AND conditions.